# change the hostname for a given service

Tags: linux, hostname

I have 2 services running on my server. The first python service is working as expected.

```
# netstat -tulpn  | grep LISTEN | grep 8888
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1057/python
```

The second node service has started but not accessible from browser at http://somesite.com:5601

```
# netstat -tulpn  | grep LISTEN | grep 5601
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4740/node
```

I guess if I can change 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 just like the first command then it should work. But I am not sure ho to change the host only for the second service. I started the second service using the command

> sudo systemctl start kibana.service

I am using ARM processor if that matters.

Comment: I used "ngrok http 5601" and it worked for some time. But then got "Too Many Connections" error.

Comment: The host that the service uses and the number of connections it can support should be defined somewhere in the service's configuration. Consult the documentation for the service in question. This is not something you should force through the operating system.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the "localhost" IP address. It is often the default listening address for services not intended to be accessed remotely. It can only be reached from the server itself (i.e. locally). 0.0.0.0 is the address you see when a service is configured to listen on *all* available IP addresses on the server.

Answer (score 2):

> Kibana has one configuration file in the conf/ folder named
> kibana.yml. You will find one keyword named server. host set your IP,
> and your Kibana will run on that IP address.

```
[root@localhost config]# vim kibana.yml

# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
#server.port: 5601
# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "192.168.99.102"
```

[https://www.edureka.co/community/72782/how-to-change-hostname-in-kibana#:~:text=Kibana%20has%20one%20configuration%20file,run%20on%20that%20IP%20address](https://www.edureka.co/community/72782/how-to-change-hostname-in-kibana#:%7E:text=Kibana%20has%20one%20configuration%20file,run%20on%20that%20IP%20address).

Answer (score 0):

It worked after adding this one line to kibana config file.

```
vi /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```